# Face Detection Parameters in Electric

Tags: ros, opencv, face-detection, ros-electric

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In previous version of ROS, you could do face detection using parameters stored in XML at `$(find opencv2)/opencv/share/opencv/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml`

In electric this file no longer exists. Where is this file now?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11699/face-detection-parameters-in-electric/) by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10932 on 2011-10-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Since I asked this, the launch files have been modified in [a branch](https://code.ros.org/svn/wg-ros-pkg/stacks/people/branches/electric_trunk/face_detector/launch/face_detector_action.wide.launch). Thanks Caroline!

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2011-10-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1